# The argument type 'SubscriptionList' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SubscriptionsList'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a problem with this code:

```
return SubscriptionTile(subscription: subscriptions[index].toString());
```

------------------------ Full Code (subscription_list.dart)------------------------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:xhub/screens/subscription/subscription_tile.dart';

class SubscriptionList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SubscriptionListState createState() => _SubscriptionListState();
}

class _SubscriptionListState extends State<SubscriptionList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final subscriptions = Provider.of<List<SubscriptionList>>(context);
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: subscriptions.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SubscriptionTile(subscription: subscriptions[index].toString());
        },
      );
  }
}
```

------------------------ Full Code (subscription_tile.dart)------------------------

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xhub/models/user.dart';

class SubscriptionTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final SubscriptionsList subscription;
  SubscriptionTile({this.subscription});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
        child: ListTile(
          leading: CircleAvatar(
            radius: 25.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          ),
          title: Text(subscription.domain),
          subtitle: Text('Renew Date: ${subscription.renew}'),
          isThreeLine: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

------------------------ Full Code (user.dart)------------------------

```
class SubscriptionsList {
  final String domain;
  final String type;
  final String plan;
  final String renew;
  final String backup;
  final String ssl;
  final String ns1;
  final String ns2;
  final String cplink;
  final String cpuser;
  final String cppass;
  final String serveruser;
  final String serverpass;
  SubscriptionsList(
      {this.domain,
      this.type,
      this.plan,
      this.renew,
      this.backup,
      this.ssl,
      this.ns1,
      this.ns2,
      this.cplink,
      this.cpuser,
      this.cppass,
      this.serveruser,
      this.serverpass});
}
```

------------------------ The Error ------------------------

```
The argument type 'SubscriptionList' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'SubscriptionsList'.
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined two SubscriptionList class. So you code must be expected one but you imported the other. Rename one of the two. For example give the SubscriptionList widget the name SubscriptionListWidget.

Comment: Thanks I've fixed the first issue, now I'm getting this:
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<List<SubscriptionsList>> above this SubscriptionList Widget

Comment: This should more be an issue with the way you use provider. I don't have enough information here to address this issue. Please be sure to have read the documentation (https://pub.dev/packages/provider). If you still can't solve your problem, please open a new stack overflow question with relevant information.